# Filter a drop-down list based on the value of a calculated value

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have a Microsoft InfoPath 2010 form linked to a list at a SharePoint Site. I would like to filter a drop-down list based on the value of a calculated value.

There is a drop-down control which contains values to be picked. These are the `Divisions` in my organization; FRD 110, FRD 120 and FRD 130. When a user selects on of these divisions then the `DivisionLong` which is a calculated value is set to the Long Name of the Division; FRD 110 = In Service Program, FRD 120 = Readiness and Cyber Security and FRD 130 = Fleet Response.

I then have two option buttons which are Yes / No for a field called `FRDGoal`. If the option of Yes is selected then a section is made visible which contains a table with two drop-down controls. The first is `Goal` and the second is `Objective`. Because each division has an objective 1; I have to have each Goal listed three times. Which when unfiltered the `Goal` drop-down contains nine total entries. So in order to not show the goals in the drop-down 9 times I would like to filter the `Goal` drop-down by the value of the `DivisionLong` so that the Goals are only show 3 times not 9.

If I select the check box in the Drop-Down properties to only show unique entries then the objectives drop-down does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make cascading combobox. You can filter your comboboxes which field u want to.

1.Right click combobox u want to filter

2.Select combobox properties

3.Below datasource list, click the box next to the entries field.

[image]

4.You can filter your comboboxes from based on another list column value & filter data.

Comment: I have done this. It works completely fine if I make DivisionLong a drop-down List (combo box), but if the control is changed to anything else then the filter does not work. If DivisionLong is a drop-down List (combo box) then the user is forced to click on it and make a selection when there is only one selection to choose from.

Comment: You can use the **Calculated Field** inplace of **dropdown-list**. It will directly sets the value like label & user don't need to select a single value like dropdown-list. You need to create an action for **Calculated Field** & do the same.

Comment: DivisionLong is already set to have the control type of calculated value. But when I set the filter on the Goals drop-down it does not filter nor display any values.

Comment: You must have to select the last value filtered from the calculated value.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by last value filtered

Comment: I said you need to change the control to **Calculated Field** & get the value in **DivisionLong** that you already did. than after you need to create an action for goals to get the data from the **DivisioLong** by as **dropdown-list** control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40288/discussion-between-troypilewski-and-hardik).